# What does it take to prove this Contract.Requires?

Tags: c#, .net, design-by-contract, microsoft-contracts

I have an application that runs through the rounds in a tournament, and I am getting a contract warning on this simplified code structure:

```
    public static void LoadState(IList<Object> stuff)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < stuff.Count; i++)
        {
            // Contract.Assert(i < stuff.Count);
            // Contract.Assume(i < stuff.Count);

            Object thing = stuff[i];

            Console.WriteLine(thing.ToString());
        }
    }
```

The warning is:

```
contracts: requires unproven: index < @this.Count
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I prove this on an `IList<T>`?  Is this a bug in the static analyzer?  How would I submit a bug report to Microsoft?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked this with version 1.2.21023.14 of code contracts and didn't get warnings. My guess is that it is a bug that has since been fixed.

Comment: Good to know.  Will check with the version 4 of the framework.

Answer (score 3):

That does look odd. Unfortunately I'm using the Pro version of VS2010 with Code Contracts, so I can't run `cccheck` myself to play around.

Do you definitely need the index rather than just using a `foreach` loop?

Just to be sure - does your simplified example above produce the same error? It's always worth checking that the simplification hasn't removed the problem :) For instance, do you do anything else to `stuff` which the contract checker might use to invalidate the guarantee about `stuff.Count`?

Comment: Yes, I checked that this simplified version does exactly that.  I this it is a bug in the static checker.  In this case, I *could* use enumeration, but to me, the "right way" seems to be to access by index (since I am accessing it in an ordered fashion.)

Comment: `foreach` is ordered when you access it on a naturally ordered collection though (like a list). You only need to worry about ordering failing for things like sets. However, that's beside the point. What happens if you uncomment each of the commented lines?

Comment: Neither has an effect.  Which is precisely why I thought it may be a bug.